# BeautifulSoup Installed but for Python3 but I'm Unable to Find the bs4 Module

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a Jupyter notebook for this on the Google Cloud Platform.

This code previously worked fine so I'm not sure what to do.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, restarting the kernals, doing a pip3 install.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. I've attached an image here.

[image: Juptyer Notebook]

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
!pip install beautifulsoup4


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

Before doing it do Runtime->Reset all runtimes

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately I'm getting the same error. Would you have any other ideas?

Comment: I did:     "!pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs"
 Try to reset the enviroment first Runtime->Reset all runtimes

Comment: just use `pip install bs4`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import bs4     

req= requests.get("https://url")
page = req.content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page) 

h1 = ...
```

And not

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```